# Can i render formatted text from firebase to vue js?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I’m creating a blog website and i need a way to format my blog-text that is stored in firebase firestore.Is there any way to keep original format of the text?(By that i mean tabs,newlines etc.)

I have tried to insert for examole \n later with javascript but when i render it in html it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the text from the firebase and display it inside some element, just give that element some class, and on that class apply this CSS-

```
.someClass {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* Preserve line breaks and tabs */
}
```

Here is a demo of this CSS-

```css
.someClass {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* Preserve line breaks and tabs */
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass">
  This is some text with
  <br>
  line breaks and    tabs. 
  <br>
  You can use the <code>&lt;br&gt;</code> tag for line breaks, and the <code>&amp;nbsp;</code> character for tabs.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In read mode, just put the text fetched from Firetsore in a `div` with the following CSS class:

```css
.text-block {
  white-space: pre-line;
  //...
}
```